# jQuery advanced dom navigation

Tags: jquery, html, dom, selector

Situation is updating shopping cart with javascript. Event comes from changing item variation from select name="variation-1". There are many .shop-items . How to get handle of input that has data-product-id if you have $(this) from change of select name="variation-1" =

```
<div class="product-tools shop-item">
    <div class="count-input">
        <a class="incr-btn" data-action="decrease" href="#">–</a>
        <input class="quantity" type="text" data-product-id="7" value="3">
        <a class="incr-btn" data-action="increase" href="#">+</a>
    </div><!-- .count-input -->                         
    <div class="form-element">
        <select name="variation-1" class="form-control form-control-sm variation-select" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="color">
            <option value="blue">blue</option>                        
            <option value="red" selected="">red</option>   
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <select name="variation-2" class="form-control form-control-sm variation-select" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="size">
            <option value="S">S</option>                        
            <option value="M">M</option>                        
            <option value="L">L</option>                        
            <option value="XL" selected="">XL</option>                        
            <option value="XXL">XXL</option>               
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you the product ID from the related input. It traverses up to the enclosing "shop-item" div, and then searches within that for the input with the "quantity" class, which has the product-it data attribute:

```
var productID = $(this).closest(".shop-item").find(".quantity").data("product-id");
```

Alternatively, if you want to find the actual element which has the "data-product-id" attribute, you can do what is suggested in the comments below:

```
var input = $(this).closest(".shop-item").find("[data-product-id]");
```

Comment: This gets the value of the input, the question asks: *"How to get handle of input"*  (just don't add the `data(..)` part)

Comment: Alternative: `$(this).closest(".shop-item").find("[data-product-id]")`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes I think you're correct. Will edit the answer.

Comment: The `find(".quantity")` would also work as the input has that class.

Comment: Works perfectly!